# How to set up a dialog box by id

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, smarty

First of all this is written in smarty, so please keep that in mind with coding styles. Its not my choice, but it is what I'm forced to work with.

I am modding a nivo banner slider to include clickabilty to links. So here is the problem. I need to pass the slide variable over to the dialog box from each slide. The goal here is to have a dialog box so I can have a user update the link to each slide as needed. The pages looks like this: http://griff4594.com/images/5-14-2013%209-05-41%20AM.png

Here is the code:

```
{literal}
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                function LinkUpload() {
                        var id = $(this).attr("rel");
                        $("#link-upload").dialog();
                        alert($id);
                }
        </script>
{/literal}


{if $slides}
<div class="ss_slides">
<ul class="ss_slides">
{foreach from=$slides item=slide}
        <li id="slide_{$slide.slideid}">
                <table class="ss_slides">
                        <tr>
                                <td class="ss_slides_image">
                                <img src="../slide-shows/{$slide.slideid}.{$slide.extention}" class="ss_thumb" />
                                <div class="ss_toolBox"><a href="#" class="ss_delete" SlideID="{$slide.slideid}" CTLID="#slide_{$slide.slideid}"><img src="uploadify/cancel.png" /></a></div>
                                </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                <td>
                                <input type="hidden" id="{$slide.slideid}" rel="{$slide.slideid}" value="{$slide.slideid}"><button type="button" onclick="LinkUpload()">Slide Link {$slide.slideid}<$
                                </td>
                        </tr>
                </table>
        </li>
{/foreach}
</ul>
</div>

{foreach from=$slides item=v}

        <div class="link-upload" title="Update Image Link" id="link-upload">
                <p>Insert the link address you wish this Slide/Banner to link to when clicked.</p>
                <form action="link_upload.php" method="POST">
                Link: <input type="text" size="40" name="link" value="{$v.link}"><br />
                <input type="submit" value="Update Link" name="update_link">
                </form>
        </div>

{/foreach}

{/if}
```

Here is the array pulled from the variable $slide so you can reference to it:

```
Array (5)
0 => Array (6)
  link => "http://google.com"
  slideid => "2"
  filename => "image235367.png"
  extention => "PNG"
  slideshowid => "1"
  iorder => "3"
1 => Array (6)
  link => "http://pvponline.com"
  slideid => "5"
  filename => "400x390px-LL-e49a9db0_2694-nooooooooo..."
  extention => "JPEG"
  slideshowid => "1"
  iorder => "2"
2 => Array (6)
  link => "http://etrade.com"
  slideid => "6"
  filename => "38783834021_large.jpg"
  extention => "JPG"
  slideshowid => "1"
  iorder => "4"
3 => Array (6)
  link => null
  slideid => "7"
  filename => "a.gif"
  extention => "GIF"
  slideshowid => "2"
  iorder => "0"
4 => Array (6)
  link => null
  slideid => "8"
  filename => "alpha.jpg"
  extention => "JPG"
  slideshowid => "2"
  iorder => "0"
```

So the dialog box right now is popping up and giving me the URLs from the database, but they are not coming up correctly by id. Meaning they are not coming up for the slide that is clicked on, like this: http://griff4594.com/images/5-14-2013%209-13-12%20AM.png

What I want is if I click on slide 1 I want a dialog box to pop up with it's link in the box. But right now it is just pulling up random ones. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you getting any errors— where's the `click` event?

Comment: no errors, just pulls up the URLs in random order and not by the id. The on click event is in the button tags in the first table, second row after the hidden input.

Comment: Try replacing `rel="{$slide.slideid}"` with `data-slideid="{$slide.slideid}"` and then `var id = $(this).data('slideid');` See if that retrieves the proper id.

Comment: I tried that before because I tend to utilize that method in most of my dynamic jquery, but I tried using REL as well. I changed my code at your suggestion anyways but still have the same problem. I am still getting the URLs randomly and not by the id like I want.

Comment: Try the answer I posted below. I'm not familiar with `smarty`, so it just addresses a possible JS issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really simplified my problem using AJAX. Here is the final solution for me.

HTML:

```
    <div id="success"></div>
<div id="error"></div>
<div class="slide-url" id="">
    <div style="font-size: 18px; text-align: center; width: 100%; padding: 10px 0;">Banner Link Update</div>
    <div id="html"></div>
    <button id="update-url">Update URL</button><button id="close-url">Close</button>
</div>
```

Here is the second part of the solution.

JQUERY:

```
$('.slide').click(function() {
var slideID = $(this).data("slide");
var risk = $(this).data("url");

$(".slide-url").show();
$("#html").html("Banner Link: <input id='surl' type='text' value="+risk+"><input type='hidden' id='sid' value=" + slideID + ">");

$("#update-url").click(function()   {
    var surl = $("#surl").val();
    var sid = $("#sid").val();
    var infoArray = {sid: "" +sid+ "", surl: "" +surl+ ""};
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "slideshow_url.php",
        data: infoArray,
        success: function(msg){
            $("#success").show();
            $("#success").html("Success!!");
            $("#success").fadeOut(5000);
            setTimeout(function()   {
                window.location.reload();
            }, 5000);
        },
        error: function(){
            $("#error").show();
            $("#error").html("Error updating URL");
            $("#error").fadeOut(5000);
        }
    });

});
    $("#close-url").click(function()    {
        $('.slide-url').hide();
        $('#success').hide()
    });
});
```

Here is the third part:

PHP:

```
$url = $_POST['surl'];
$id = $_POST['sid'];

db_query("UPDATE xcart_slideshow_slides SET url='$url' WHERE slideid='$id'");

echo "URL Updated to " . $url;
```

Works wonderfully and does what I need it to. I have tried to do this a couple of times but figured it out after doing a few more related ajax projects.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is `$( this )` in your function `LinkUpload` references the `button`, and not the hidden `input`

```
      function LinkUpload() {
                    var id = $(this).attr("rel"); 
                    $("#link-upload").dialog();
                    alert($id);
                    }
```

I would change it to:

```
      function LinkUpload() {
                    var id = $( this ).parent().attr( "rel" );
                    $( "#link-upload" ).dialog();
                    alert($id);
            }
```

**EDIT**

I'm not very familiar with `smarty`, but, based on the screencast you posted, it appears like it's brining up the correct URL the first-time, and then the next URL in the `array` on subsequent calls.

The last loop could be problematic:

```
  {foreach from=$slides item=v}
    <div class="link-upload" title="Update Image Link" id="link-upload">
            <p>Insert the link address you wish this Slide/Banner to link to when clicked.</p>
            <form action="link_upload.php" method="POST">
            Link: <input type="text" size="40" name="link" value="{$v.link}"><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Update Link" name="update_link">
            </form>
    </div>
  {/foreach}
```

If the above loop is creating multiple versions of `#link-upload` then you need to use a unique `ID` for each version, like `#link-upload-01, 02, etc`, or else, the call to `$("#link-upload").dialog();` won't work properly. Also, I'm not sure this is better than just creating one *dialog* , but I don't have enough insight into what you're building to recommend that confidently.

```
            function LinkUpload() {
                   var id    = $( this ).prev('input').attr("rel"),
                     , input = $( '#link-upload' ).find( '.slidelink' );

                     input.val( id );

                    $("#link-upload").dialog();

                    alert(id);
                  }
    </script>


 <div class="link-upload" title="Update Image Link" id="link-upload">
        <form action="link_upload.php" method="POST">
             <input class="slidelink" type="text" size="40" name="link" value="0"><br />
             <input type="submit" value="Update Link" name="update_link">
        </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: Tried that too. Still same problem. Here is a screencast of the problem, so you can see how it functions: [http://griff4594.com/images/5-14-2013%2010-30-55%20AM.mp4]

Comment: It appears that the URL is correct the first time `LinkUpload` is called, but, random on subsequent calls ?

Comment: yes pretty much, or it is just cycling through each URL in the database. I need it to call just the individual URL. I think it is actually just the foreach statement at the bottom. The one that has the dialog content. It should be bringing up just the one box that is equal to the jquery variable $id

Comment: but I also need to make sure the slideid is passed to the dialog box because I have to process a form in the dialog box to update the URL if needed.

Comment: One dialog would solve the problem so long as it updated to the slideid selected.

Comment: So if I wanted to create just a single dialog box and it would pull up just the info for the slide selected, would I do something like:

    id="link-upload{$id}"

inside of the div for the dialog box? I'm not sure how to pass that jquery variable to the dialog box. How do I make sure it is just for that one slide?

Comment: I created a rough solution above, try doing something like that.

Comment: Interesting....but right now it isn't passing the variable. But I see what you are trying to do. I get nothing in the value right now.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UBaNF/ — Here's a simple test, so you can see how it would work.

Comment: Can you take a look at this? This is the closest this fiddle is to my script: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/griff4594/Rtu7g/)